# Vbscript to change windows service startuptype

Tags: command-line, vbscript, windows-services

I am using the below command line code to change the start up type of some of my services to automatic-delayed.

```
sc config *servicename*  start= delayed-auto
```

Is there a way to do this in VBscript? Or can the above command line be converted to VBScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `Run` Method**

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "CMD /C sc config *servicename*  start= delayed-auto", 0, True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
    WshShell.Run chr(34) & "sc.exe"" config *servicename* start=demand""" & Chr(34), 0, false
    Set WshShell = Nothing 

    ' auto--a service automatically started at boot time, even if no user logs on
    ' boot--a device driver loaded by the boot loader
    ' demand--a service that must be manually started (the default)
    ' disabled--a service that can't be started
    ' system--a service started during kernel initialization
    ' delayed-auto ???????????
    ' 0 - hidden, 1 - normal mode 2 - minimized view 3 - expanded view
```